Diff date cumulated
I need to calculated a difference (+1) between date but the end date is static for each value. And I need to collect the information for use it for another formula. (in this case date diff date *5)
I can't add the difference in a table because the dataset is not mine. I can only use DAX.



First DATE
End DATE
data diff
Result




01/01/2024
02/01/2024
2
10


01/01/2024
03/01/2024
3
15


01/01/2024
04/01/2024
4
20



I try the formula diff date but I don't know how to select the last date.
I need a DAX formula

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Before I created [Primo mese]
and after I have done the following formula
Diff = 
VAR EndDate = LASTDATE(DIM_DATE[Date])
VAR DateDiff = DATEDIFF([Primo mese], EndDate, DAY) + 1 
RETURN DateDiff * 5


Is this a solution to your question or a complimentary comment ?
